# Log or debug Firebase HttpMetric trace calls for iOS (without waiting 12h)

Tags: ios, firebase, debugging, logging

By default, you can add HttpMetric calls with Firebase, and then you can wait 12h for the metrics to show up on the Firebase dashboard under the Networking section...

But that's really not that great if you just want to verify you're doing things right, and you have to wait 12h to find out...

Regular events can be verified via the Debug section (i.e. trace events, but not networking or HttpMetric data) via this:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview

On Android, you can enable logging to verify that the network logging integration is working properly - based on these instructions:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android#debugging_integration

## But there doesn't seem to be any corresponding way to log the HttpMetric information for iOS in real time or near real time...

Right now, I have network logging showing up (i.e. the basic Performance Monitoring).  Yesterday, I added a few custom HttpMetric traces, and I've verified that both stop and start are successfully called with correct attributes... but the custom attributes have not shown up yet.  Waiting 12h to test that it's working (or that it should be) is very cumbersome.

It would be great if there were a way to view what would be logged in the app's console output (like Android's mldb logcat via the second link above)...

Or if the Firebase Debug event viewer showed the network calls...

Is there anything else that can be used for this???

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Sorry, haven't... but I haven't been trying in some time... I may check on this again since you asked - maybe something has changed... were you running into a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-ios#view-log-messages

It allows logging the request on the IDE output console.